# Why Do I Have So Many Dbus Processes Running?

Tags: system, dbus

According to my system monitor there are 24 dbus processes running, the owner is lp. Need I be alarmed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless these deamons are consuming a lot of CPU or other resources there's no cause for alarm.  I believe the cups service is in play here.  Perhaps you have a lot of printers in your environment.  Or a lot of print jobs running.

you should have a half dozen or so dbus processes running but rarely executing on a home computer.  More on a machine being used as a print server.

The following command will tell you more about who owns these daemons:

`ps -ef | grep dbus`

I'm guessing it's cups.  Since you have no printers connected you can try stopping cups:

`service cups stop`

There are other services that communicate using dbus but since `lp` owns the process in this case, I'm assuming it's cups (or SMB / Samba) that's in play.

Before you disable anything, go into system settings->printers and verify that in fact you do not have any printer connections set up.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't have any printers. I don't know where the processes are coming from.

Comment: It seems to have sorted itself out, I only show six or so now, no impact on my system :)

Comment: I checked system settings there are no printers setup.